# Async Loop Not Honoring Async

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous, promise

I have been a bit stuck on an Async function.

**What I am trying to accomplish** - I am creating a batchProcessing function (batchGetSubs) which will loop through a set of files, read a ID, then make an API request, wait for a response (**THE ISSUE**) and then to write to a new file with the formatted data.

**The issue** - I have tried both Async and Await, as well as pushing promises and trying to use a Promise.all to wait for promises to be resolved, but with no success. Current behavior is that I get all of my console.logs that are in the Promise.all section before the API calls actually return all the data. I have used these articles as reference:

- [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop)
- [Promise All with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669596/promise-all-with-axios#)
- [Javascript Promise push value into array (only from function or outside?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113973/javascript-promise-push-value-into-array-only-from-function-or-outside)

**The Code** -

```
async function batchGetSubs(data, command) {
    console.time('batchGetSubs')
    iteration = 1;
    let dataArray = []; promises = [];

    // LOOP THROUGH FILES, THEN GET TENANTS BY SUB
    for (i = iteration; i < totalIterations; i++) {
        let msIds = await loopAndDump(iteration);

        // LOOP THROUGH TENANTIDS AND GET SUBSCRIPTIONS
        msIds.map(async item => {
            let newRecord = await getSubsByTenantId(item);
            promises.push(await newRecord);
        });
        }
        Promise.all([promises]).then(() => { // FIXME: WHY IS THIS NOT WAITING FOR ALL RESPONSES?
            console.log(p1SubscriptionArray),
            console.timeEnd('batchGetSubs')
        });
    }



async function getSubsByTenantId(msTenantId) {
    let newRecord; let subscriptionArray = [];
    let bearerToken = p1BearerToken;
    let totalSubs = 0;
    const subIdConfig = {
        method: 'get',
        url: ``,
        headers: { 'Authorization': bearerToken }
    }
    await delay();
    await axios(subIdConfig)
        .then(async res => {
            console.log('AXIOS RESPONSE', res.data);
            if (res.data.items) {
                let subItems = res.data.items;
                console.log('^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^', res.data.items)
                // LOOP THROUGH AND ADD TO SUBSCRIPTION ARRAY
                subItems.map(async subscription => {
                    if (subscription.friendlyName) {
                        totalSubs++;
                        subscriptionArray.push(subscription.friendlyName);
                    }
                });
                newRecord = { "tenantId": msTenantId, "totalSubs": totalSubs, "subscriptionFriendlyName": subscriptionArray };
            } else {
                // NO SUBS
                newRecord = { "tenantId": msTenantId, "totalSubs": totalSubs, "subscriptionFriendlyName": ['NONE'] };
                let statusCode, errorMessage;
                if (error && error.response === undefined) { // GETTING STATUS -4039 or -4077 INSTEAD OF 429 WHEN CHECKING SUBS. FORCE A RESEND.
                    if (error.errno && error.errno === -4039 || error.errno && error.errno === -4077) statusCode = 429; errorMessage = error.code;
                } else {
                    statusCode = error.response.status;
                    errorMessage = error.response.statusText;
                }
                console.error('ERROR:: SUBIDCONFIG SECTION THROWING ERROR: ', statusCode, portal, errorMessage);
                // SORT NON-200 CALLS BASED ON STATUS CODE
                switch (statusCode) {
                    case 403:
                        status403.push('subs', newRecord);
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        status404.push('subs', newRecord);
                        erroring = true;
                        break;
                    case 429:
                        status429.push('subs', newRecord);
                        erroring = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        statusOther.push('subs', newRecord)
                        erroring = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            newRecord = { "tenantId": msTenantId, "totalSubs": totalSubs, "subscriptionFriendlyName": ['NONE'] };
            console.error('ERROR: REQUEST IN GETSUBSBYTENANTID(): ', err)
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log('DO WE HAVE ANY INFORMATION? ', newRecord);
            p1SubscriptionArray.push(newRecord);
            resolve();
        });
}
```

Comment: The indentation of Promise.all is distractingly wrong.

Comment: I think you can put `return` before `Promise.all` to return the promise, or you can `await` the chained `Promise.all(...).then(...)`

Comment: The `promises` array is fully populated _after_ being passed to `Promise#all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only checked the first function, where you had put your question:

> WHY IS THIS NOT WAITING FOR ALL RESPONSES?

For several reasons:

1. The `promise` array is still empty when you call `Promise.all`. This is because you only do a `push` *after* an `await`, and so that `push` happens asynchronously (read: *later*).
2. Even when the `promises` array gets populated, it will not have promises objects, but resolved values (i.e. `newRecord` values)
3. Even if `promises` would have been array of promises, you don't pass that array correctly to `Promise.all`: you wrap that array in yet another array, which then only has one entry, and that entry is not a promise, but an array.

Not related to your problem, but:

- please make it a habit to explicitly declare all your variables. You did not do this for `iteration`, `promises`, nor `i`.
- Only use `.map` when you do something with the return value. For pure iteration use `.forEach` or `for`. In this case, you *can* use the return value to extend the `promises` array.
- If you intend to call `batchGetSubs` and need to know when all is done, then make sure it returns a useful promise: *return* `Promise.all()`

Here is the suggested correction for that function:

```
async function batchGetSubs(data, command) {
    console.time('batchGetSubs')
    let iteration = 1; // Declare!
    let dataArray = []; 
    let promises = []; // declare

    // declare i
    for (let i = iteration; i < totalIterations; i++) {
        let msIds = await loopAndDump(iteration);

        // Use the return value of the map method. No need for async callback
        promises.push(...msIds.map(item => {
            // Get the promise, not the resolved value, as that will come too late:
            return getSubsByTenantId(item);
        }));
    }
    // promises is already an array; don't make it an array of arrays.
    // And: return the resulting promise: it may be useful to the caller.
    return Promise.all(promises).then(() =>  {
        console.log(p1SubscriptionArray),
        console.timeEnd('batchGetSubs')
    });
}
```

Comment: This is perfect and works as needed. I see that I nested things more than I should have and declaring promises = msIds.map... was the saver for me. 

I have the variables declared at another section as well and should have mentioned that ahead of time. Thank you for this!

Comment: Good to hear. Note a change I had to make.

Answer (score 0):

You do a await **and** then in the same time.
You do a promise/then **or** await/async

do

```
async function getSubsByTenantId(msTenantId) {
    let newRecord; let subscriptionArray = [];
    let bearerToken = p1BearerToken;
    let totalSubs = 0;
    const subIdConfig = {
        method: 'get',
        url: ``,
        headers: { 'Authorization': bearerToken }
    }
    await delay();
    const r = await axios(subIdConfig)
    const reponse = r.data
    console.log(response)
}
```

if you want to try catch do this :

```
async function getSubsByTenantId(msTenantId) {
    let newRecord; let subscriptionArray = [];
    let bearerToken = p1BearerToken;
    let totalSubs = 0;
    const subIdConfig = {
        method: 'get',
        url: ``,
        headers: { 'Authorization': bearerToken }
    }
    await delay();
    let r
    try {
      r = await axios(subIdConfig)
    } catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
    }
    const reponse = r.data
    console.log(response)
}
```

Comment: When you did **await**, you cancel the promise so your **then** cannot be apply.